# how to get the env variables set inside an apache server process

Tags: apache, environment-variables

i am using an apache server.
Actually i have written a few modules which run when the apache service is started with
apachectl.

I have set certain env variables in envvars at
/usr/local/apache2/bin/envvars

Now i start the httpd process with
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start.

Now this apache process will initiate another child apache process.
I would like to know the enviroment variables set in both these processes? How can i see that?

Answer (score -1):

ok sorry, i found it.

cat /proc//environ